# How do I add a property to a breeze entity in the ViewModel, to assist with View display?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

How do I add a knockoutobserable property to a breeze entity - IsSelected(), in the ViewModel, to assist with View display?

IsSelected is not a field in the entity nor should it be, however I need to flag entites as selected for UI DOM manipulation (adding/removing css classes, etc.)

IsSelected is really a UI thing, but this is where the MVVM pattern gets cloudy for me.

Comment: The purist would say that adding `isSelected` to your model entity is wrong because it's a UI fact, not a business model fact. And it could bite you later as when you display the entity on TWO screens and it should be selected on one screen but not the other. The purist would say you should create an "ItemViewModel" which contained the entity and the UI facts about it.  To which you might reply, "yes ... you're right ... but for now I'm going to do what @Nathan says; it won't be hard to "fix this" later if I have to ... which I probably won't."

Comment: @Ward -isSelected does seem (to me) like something that solely belongs in the UI, maintained by the view, but I could not do that as the items were populated from a knockout foreach loop, the view is loaded by an $.ajax call, and bound on the success callback, so at the point of domready for the view, the databind has not yet occurred. so if I were to just do this in the viewmodel (rather than adding to the model), my only idea was to maintain some kind of auxilary hash table of selected items, so Nathan's solution was much easier!

Comment: @nathan's answer is clearly easier. For giggles, you can create an "ItemViewModel" which is a wrapper around your entity. It could be a two property thing: `{item: ko.observable(the-breeze-entity), isSelected: ko.observable(false)}`; you probably don't need to make `item` be observable. Anyway, in the view you bind to a KO array of these guys. Bind through it to get to the nested entity properties, e.g., "...`item().firstName`". Yuck ... but it works. Or live with the impurity ... as I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend your breeze entities by using the `metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor` method

In some of my projects I have a separate function to extend each entity.

So you will end up with something like this.

```
function extendProduct(metadataStore) {
    var ctor = function () {

    };
    var initialiser = function (entity) {
        entity.isSelected= ko.observable(false);

        return entity;
    };

    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Product', ctor, initialiser);
}
```

I generally use the initialiser as it gets called after breeze has hydrated the entity by adding all its additional properties etc.

I generally stay away from the contstructor method as it gets called as the very first step in breeze   hydrating the entity.